# Exception is printed twice

Tags: java, file-io

```
class Patmatch {
  static String strLine="";

  public static void main(String [] args) {    
    try {
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c://abc.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));           
      while ((strLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        try {
          Patternmatch();
        }
        catch(NomatchException me) {
          System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        }
      }
      in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException i) {
      System.out.println("exec:"+i);
    }   
  }

  private static void Patternmatch() throws NomatchException {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("---"); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);  
    if(m.find()) { 
      System.out.print(m.start()); 
    }
    else { 
      throw new NomatchException("no match"); 
    } 
  }
}

class NomatchException extends Exception {
  NomatchException(String s) {
    super(s);
  }
}
```

In the above code Exception no match is printed twice.

I have abc.txt where i don't have the pattern ---.

I can understand that in that `main` i have caught this exception and also in `NomatchException()` i have thrown but if i remove the `try...catch` it shows error and if the remove in `nomatchException()` nothing s displayed.

What should I do now to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only calling `System.out.print()` once, but you are doing it in a `while` loop.  Perhaps you have extra lines at the end of `abc.txt` which cause your loop to continue.

EDIT in response to comment:

> What shoud i do even if i have so many lines exception should be printed once but if i have --- in many places all those positions must be printed?

First - please note that Exceptions should not be used to control the flow of your program - generally, they are meant to only happen in exceptiional circumstances.

Now, if you want to indicate that you found *at least* 1 non-matching line in `abc.txt`, then you can redesign your program such that your `Patternmatch()` will return a `boolean` result, and based on that return value you can increment a new `errorCnt` field.  If this new counter is greater than zero, you can print your informational message.

If, however, you would like to simply omit the error from appearing for empty lines in text, you can put a simple test in your `Patternmatch()` method to test the length of the `trim()`'d string:

```
  if (strLine.trim().length() > 0 ) {
      //do your test
  }
```

Also - a note on naming in Java.  Class names start with a capital letter (so `nomatchException` should be `NomatchException`) and method names start with a lowercase letter (`Patternmatch()` should be `patternmatch()`).

Comment: ya i tried removing the second line and now only once its displayed. What shoud i do even if i have so many lines exception should be printed once but if i have --- in many places all those positions must be printed?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with akf - exceptions should be exceptional. Another way to control your logic flow could be:

```
while (((strLine = br1.readLine()) != null)) {
   if (!Patternmatch())
      System.out.println("no match");
}
```

and modifying your `Patternmatch()`

```
private static boolean Patternmatch() throws NomatchException {       
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("---");        
   Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);         

   return m.find();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have two lines in your text file that don't match.

As the others have said, this is a poor use of exceptions. Have the patternMatch() method return a boolean.